# Use AppBar Style on a TabBar that is not its child

Tags: flutter

I want my tab bar to have the same styling as the AppBar.
(using the same icon color, text color and background color)

My layout features a tabbed section to the left and another column to the right. Whithout additional styling the TabBar icons are not visible because both they and the background are white.

So what would be the most convinient way to apply the AppBar style to the TabBar? Thanks for any suggestions!

[image: App Screenshot]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => MyAppState();
}

class MyAppState extends State<MyApp> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  TabController _tabController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _tabController = TabController(
      vsync: this,
      length: 3,
      initialIndex: 0,
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double bigSize = IconTheme.of(context).size * 4.0;
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: new ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Flutter TabBar Style Problem'),
        ),
        body: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 36.0,
                    child: TabBar(
                      controller: _tabController,
                      tabs: [
                        Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.cake)),
                        Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.train)),
                        Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.info)),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  Flexible(
                    child: TabBarView(
                      controller: _tabController,
                      children: [
                        Icon(Icons.cake, size: bigSize),
                        Icon(Icons.train, size: bigSize),
                        Icon(Icons.info, size: bigSize),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: Container(
                  color: Colors.amber.shade400,
                  alignment: FractionalOffset.center,
                  child: Text('Another Column'),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ), 
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You could set tabbar inside appbar: appBar: AppBar(
        bottom: TabBar()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you place a `TabBar` as the `bottom:` widget of the `AppBar` you get a lot of things for free. It gets the background color and a Material widget that has a special feature. It forces the indicator to use white color when the default indicator color is the same as the background color [(give a look here)](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/2ea1d81cdc5ccb457240b649b49d0ccedbf32794/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/tabs.dart#L713).

So when you place a `TabBar` outside the `AppBar` you have to handle everything yourself.

But it seems pretty easy wrapping the TabBar in a `Material` and giving it the `primaryColor` ([the same the framework does here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/2ea1d81cdc5ccb457240b649b49d0ccedbf32794/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/app_bar.dart#L491)).

So at the end is just replacing your `SizedBox` by a `Material` and setting the color. And you get the ink splash for free.

```
          Material(
            color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
            child: TabBar(
              controller: _tabController,
              tabs: [
                Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.cake)),
                Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.train)),
                Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.info)),
              ],
            ),
          ),
```

Comment: This solution may work but it is not a good way to solve this problem

Comment: Well, you have provided an answer with the official TabBar. I have provided a solution that solves the MP problem. My goal was not to discuss the design proposed by the MP. I don't know his requirements.

Comment: While your answer produces the desired output for the given example it will break once a different theme is applied to the app. I really need to use the styles that the app bar uses to make it work consistently.

Comment: You are right. This was a quick example as I didn't have the IDE to test it. The right way to set the colors is to get them from the Theme. But I had thought that was the easy part. Will update the answer with the whole customization.

Comment: To me that is the difficult part and the point of my question. How do I know which theme styles are applied on which elements. Is there a way to retrieve that information fron given layout maybe using the flutter inspector?

Comment: I have edited my answer and I think it is the way to go. Easier than I thought by looking into the framework.

Comment: Have you tried the solution that I've given in the edited answer? Sorry that I didn't make it clear in the comment. Using a `Material` widget solves everything: color, icons, indicator, ink splash, etc. In fact, that's what the `AppBar` uses under the hood for the `TabBar`.

Comment: Yep, I am afraid though the indicator color is not displayed correctly. The indicator color is buried way down in the framework and I have to admit I still havn't found the place where it is defined.

Comment: Oops, I should have just copied and pasted your solution! Of course it works like a charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What appBar interally do is inserting a custom DefaultTextStyle that points to Theme.textTheme.title

You can do the exact same thing by wrapping a part of your widget tree into a custom DefaultTextStyle.

```
DefaultTextStyle(
  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.title,
  child: Text('Title')
);
```

As for the background color, it is availble in another field of Theme.

```
Container(
  color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
);
```

Comment: Thanks, that helped a lot. I still have one problem though: The indicator line at the bottom of the tabbar is now gone. It is always blue irrespective of the current selection. (selected tab should have a white bottom line in line with the appbar embedded tabbar)

Answer (score 0):

Change Your Code to Something Like This:

```
    class ProductsAdminPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // Scaffold is inside DefaultTabController because DefaultTabController needs access to Scaffold
    return DefaultTabController(
      // Number of tabs
      length: 2,
      child: Scaffold(
        drawer: Drawer(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              AppBar(
                automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
                title: Text('Choose'),
              ),
              ListTile(
                title: Text('All Products'),
                onTap: () {
                  Navigator.pushReplacement(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => ProductsPage()));
                },
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Manage Products'),
          // TabBar is added as the bottom widget of the appBar
          bottom: TabBar(
            tabs: <Widget>[
              // No of Tab() Widgets Should be equal to length
              Tab(
                icon: Icon(Icons.create),
                text: 'Create Product',
              ),
              Tab(
                icon: Icon(Icons.list),
                text: 'My Products',
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        body: TabBarView(
          // No of pages should be equal to length
          children: <Widget>[ProductCreatePage(), ProductListPage()],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I am afraid this won't preserve my layout.

Answer (score 0):

```
 ThemeData(
  appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(
    ...
  ),
  tabBarTheme: TabBarTheme(
    labelColor: Colors.black,
    unselectedLabelColor: Colors.grey,
    indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.label,
    labelStyle: TextStyle(
      fontSize: 20.0,
      color: Colors.green,
    ),
    unselectedLabelStyle: TextStyle(
      fontSize: 20.0,
      color: Colors.green,
    ),
  ),
);
```

We can customise theme in App Level theme as our app bar and then every where in app, tabs will use same style as we define in theme.
I hope it is the easiest approach...